# Finding possible code coverage paths for simple function

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm having a hard time trying to cover all paths for code coverage for a particular class method:

```
public function getTotalOfType(String $type) : float
{
    $total = 0;

    foreach($this->getCartItemsOfType($type) as $cartitem)
    {
        $total += $cartitem->getAmount();
    }

    return $total;
}
```

`getCartItemsOfType()` will only ever return an array - either empty or populated with cart items.

My current coverage states that I have covered two paths but that a third one is missing. Branch and line coverage show 100%. My assertations are below. I have omitted set up:

```
...
@test
@covers Cart::getTotalOfType()
...

$this->assertEquals(10, $cart->getTotalOfType('shoes')); //passes
$this->assertEquals(20, $cart->getTotalOfType('jumper')); //passes
$this->assertEquals(0, $cart->getTotalOfType('does_not_exist')); //passes as type does not exist
$this->assertEquals(0, $cart->getTotalOfType('')); //passes - empty string returns 0
```

I'm missing one possible permutation but can't seem to figure out what.

What are the possible path permutations for this function?

Below are the results from my code coverage report:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can `getCartItemsOfType()` or `getAmount()` throw exceptions?

Comment: No - the signature is `public function getCartItemsOfType(String $class) : Array` if that helps.

Comment: And signature of `getAmount()` is `public function getAmount() : float`

Comment: Grasping at straws here - but what if the method returns a `float` instead of an `int`?  Is that considered a different path?

Comment: I think you meant "return an int instead of a float". I don't think so. The value is pulled from a DB with type of float. Also, since the function is return typed it should only return a float and nothing else. There is also the issue of what other types I'd have to check against - bool, string, object? I'm wondering if it is to do with what my tests covers (although I am not sure). I'll add that to my question and see if that helps.

Comment: Hard to say, what do you mean by "covered two paths but that a third one is missing"? Does it mention the paths? What if you export the test result with `<report><html outputDirectory="html-coverage"/></report>`? You could actually browse the code and see what lines are tested and not tested.

Comment: Thanks @SteeveDroz. I've added the screenshots of my report relating to this method. I suppose it boils down to understanding how to read this and find out what path is not covered. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I have no idea what it is. Usually, the code coverage report shows your code, without duplicate lines. What coverage tool are you using?

Comment: It's the phpunit one - phpunit/php-code-coverage. I know there are other formats like clover, cobertura and crap4j that I can generate from phpunit. Any recommendation?

Comment: Join me on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php to discuss about it.